# How can I make previous item's button visible when click on current item's button in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

What I want is when I click the "x" button of the second item, it will remove the second item and then make the "+" of the first item visible. Here is what I try but not work, the "+" button is not showed.

```
holder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            View view = recyclerView.getChildAt(position - 1);
            holder.ivAdd = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_add_items);
            holder.ivAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            list.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
  });
```

Comment: can you also post the xml?

Comment: btw, why are you initializing the image inside the onclick? don't you have a custom view holder?

Comment: yes I have a view holder, but I dont know how to get the image of the previous item so I tried that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
holder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                View view = recyclerView.getChildItemId(position - 1);
                holder.ivAdd = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_add_items);
                holder.ivAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                list.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
      });
```

I hope that will help you for solving your problem.